# ConTeXt: Primes (derivatives) look wrong when using mathdesign

Tags: fonts, symbols, context

The following example:

```
\loadtypescriptfile[mathdesign]
\setupbodyfont[charter,12pt]

\starttext
\startTEXpage[offset=3bp]
Derivatives look bad: $y''=(y')'$.

Also in a displayed formula:
\startformula
f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt.
\stopformula
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

Gives the output:

[image: image showing primes that are incorrect]

I use

```
ConTeXt  ver: 2018.02.25 19:48 MKIV beta  fmt: 2018.3.2  int: english/english
```

Running `pdffonts` on the pdf file, I get

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
IGTPXN+Bitstream-Charter             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     10  0
HBTNTB+CharterBT-Italic              Type 1            Custom           yes yes no      11  0
OVWAZT+MathDesign-CH-Regular-Symbol-10 Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      12  0
WNUDUP+Bitstream-Charter             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
VZLEXX+MathDesign-CH-Regular-Extension-10 Type 1            Builtin          yes yes no      14  0
CEWEBK+Bitstream-Charter             CID Type 0C       Identity-H       yes yes yes     15  0
```

> Question: How can I make the primes look normal?

Comment: Ah, the primes again.  See those threads: https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088926.html, https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088747.html, https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/088699.html, and https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089541.html.  I don't think there is much you can do.

Comment: @HenriMenke Thank you for your comment. I thought that the primes were a problem only for open type fonts (as you see I've been writing in some of those threads). It is a pity if this is not solvable, then the mathdesign font will be useless in ConTeXt. Maybe a better place to ask this is the list? I just have a feeling Hans is fed up with these type of math font questions...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I proposed in https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2017/089541.html, you can restore the classic Plain TeX behaviour for primes by simply copy-pasting the definition from `plain.tex` into your document.  I used Iwona here because Mathdesign is not bundled with Standalone, but Iwona shows the same problem with primes.  The only adjustment you have to make, is insert an explicit kern after `\prime` in the definition of `\prim@s`.  Otherwise LuaTeX will attempt to ligature the two single primes into `U+2033 DOUBLE PRIME` which is not available (at least in Iwona).

By applying this workaround you however lose all the Unicode features of primes in ConTeXt, i.e. you can only enter primes as `'` (`U+0027 APOSTROPHE`).  No `′` (`U+2032 PRIME`), `″` (`‎U+2033 DOUBLE PRIME`), or `‴` (`U+2034 TRIPLE PRIME`).

I think you're better off using OpenType math fonts.

```
\setupbodyfont[iwona,12pt]

\catcode`@=11
% from plain.tex
\mathcode`\'="8000 % ^\prime
{\catcode`\'=\active \gdef'{^\bgroup\prim@s}}
\def\prim@s{\prime\mkern0mu\futurelet\next\pr@m@s}
\def\pr@m@s{\ifx'\next\let\nxt\pr@@@s \else\ifx^\next\let\nxt\pr@@@t
  \else\let\nxt\egroup\fi\fi \nxt}
\def\pr@@@s#1{\prim@s} \def\pr@@@t#1#2{#2\egroup}
\catcode`@=12

\starttext

\startTEXpage[offset=3bp]
Derivatives look bad: $y''=(y')'$.

Also in a displayed formula:
\startformula
f(x) = f(0)+\int_0^x f'(t)\,dt.
\stopformula
\stopTEXpage
\stoptext
```

#### Before:

[image]

#### After:

[image]

Comment: Indeed, this works well, also for mathdesign (which comes with the standalone if you add `--fonts=all`. I will accept this answer and send an email to the list suggesting Hans to make this an option for `\setupmathematics`. Thank you!